# How to use intent in android react native module

Tags: java, android, react-native

I wrote codes to access android native from react native, 
to show the toast-like example on react native docs http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html 
It works well, but when I try to use intent, there's an error.
Can someone help?

```
package com.myApp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

public class QRModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule{

    public QRModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "QRCode";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void show(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,DimoActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        //Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: can u put error of android studio.

Comment: You should share your code in the question for two reasons.
1) If someone wants to help you, they can't just copy-paste your code because you shared an image.
2) The link might break so other people won't be able to use the help that you get.

Comment: We need the exact error text, not the picture please.

Comment: i'm sorry i was added my code above, i think that because QRmodule class is not extend from AppCompatActivity, can someone help?

Comment: Did you find any fix regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this great package: [react-native-intent-launcher](https://github.com/poberwong/react-native-intent-launcher)

Answer (score 0):

a simple way.

In your QRModule you need to call the reactContext that contain the Activity reference from react native.

```
getCurrentActivity().startActivity(intent,CODE);
```